# Graphviz, change dot cpu usage limit

Tags: cpu, graphviz, dot

Im using schemaspy to generate a db documentation, it uses dot, but dot only uses 25% of the cpu, is there a way to change/control the cpu usage of dot? im not using the computer for anything else, so i can let it use 100% of the cpu to finish faster.

Im using

Windows 7 x64.

2x4gb ddr3 ram

core i7 2620m.

Comment: What version of GraphViz are you using?

Comment: @SualehFatehi Schemaspy_5.0.0 Graphviz2-38 jtds-1.3.1 as mssql driver SchemaspyGUI